# php textarea validation form refresh not working as required

Tags: php, html, css

this html code

```
<div class="textarea_box"> <strong><span>*</span> Tooltip Message to be displayed:</strong>
            <?php $class = 'correct';if (isset($flag) && ($flag == 4)){$class = 'wrong';}$content = isset($disp_msg) ? $disp_msg : "";?>
            <textarea name="txtDispMsg" cols="1" rows="1" class="<?php echo $class; ?>"><?php echo $content;?></textarea>
</div>
```

this is css code

```
#Form1 textarea .wrong {
border:2px solid #F00;
}
```

all is well except in case of error it does not make textarea border red (i.e. #F00)
what could be wrong? guys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the space in your selector, `#Form1 textarea .wrong` should be `#Form1 textarea.wrong`

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS is saying look for an element with a class of 'wrong' within the textarea, when instead it should look for a textarea with a class of 'wrong'

```
#Form1 textarea.wrong { ... }
```